# Sheet 1 has three tables with same headers separated by 1 row. Copy Every table into new sheet and merge three tables into 1

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Hi Everyone, I'm trying to merge a data dump from the web into one single data table in Excel using VBA. 
The data dump is structured like the picture attached:

1. 4 Header Columns
2. 3 tables, all with the same headers
3. Between every table there are a few rows of space.

What I'm trying to do:

4. Copy the header from the first table into Sheet 2
5. Copy the data from the first table under the header row in Sheet 2
6. Copy data from second table (not the header row) into Sheet 2 under the first table
7. Copy data from third table (not the header row) into Sheet 2 under the first and second table.

I'm getting stuck on #6 above.

```
For I = 2 To wb2.Sheets.Count
Sheets(I).Activate
Set OI1 = Range("A3:AM" & Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row)
OI1.Select
OI1Count = Selection.Rows.Count + 4
OI1.Copy Sheets("All Outstanding Invoices").Range("A" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set OI1 = Nothing

Sheets(I).Activate
Set OI2 = Range("A3").Offset(OI1Count, 0)
OI2.Select
```

I want to offset from first selected table by the size of the first table + the number of empty rows, then create a new range which would select my second table. But i'm stuck on how to do that.

```
 Set OI2 = Range("A3").Offset(OI1Count, 0)
OI2.Select
```

What i need is for something like

```
 Set OI2 = Range("A3:AM").Offset(OI1Count,0)
 OI2.End(xlDown).Row
```

But that doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: Creating actual Data Tables (List Objects in VBA) enables you to use Structured Referencing that will make the code a lot cleaner :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Entirely new to VBA :$ and what I've created so far is all from some Google Fu. Could you direct me to some resources :)

Comment: Now that I read this again, does the data dump always come in this format? Is it a copy paste? Or do you manually place? Or do you do it through code?

Comment: It's an excel extract from a website. The data format always comes like this (not sure why it was designed this way). To give you some context, the first table shows Invoices that are >7 days Late, Second table shows Invoices <7 days late and third table shows invoices in another departments queues.

Answer (score 1):

Create [Data Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) for all three tables (three in your example). You should be able to create the tables and still receive the extract from the website.

Assuming you name them `t1`, `t2` and `t3`, respectively, you can then work with them through VBA in the following way to accomplish your task:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConsolidateTableData()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Worksheets("ExtractData") 'change name as needed.

    Dim wsConsolidated As Worksheet
    Set wsConsolidated = Worksheets("ConsolidatedData") 'change as needed

    With wsData

        .ListObjects("t1").HeaderRowRange.Copy wsConsolidated.Range("A1")
        .ListObjects("t1").DataBodyRange.Copy wsConsolidated.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .ListObjects("t2").DataBodyRange.Copy wsConsolidated.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .ListObjects("t3").DataBodyRange.Copy wsConsolidated.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    End With

End Sub
```

See [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Using Area is more efficient.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, rngDB As Range, rngT As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB

    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    Set toWs = Sheets(2)

    Set rngDB = Ws.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    toWs.UsedRange.Clear
    toWs.Range("a1").Resize(1, 4) = Ws.Range("a1").Resize(1, 4).Value

    For Each rng In rngDB.Areas
        vDB = rng.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1)
        Set rngT = toWs.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Next rng

End Sub
```